# play framework can't read cookie and can't parse request header

Tags: playframework-2.0

play framework can't read cookie and can't parse request header.
the error logs are these:

```
[play.api.mvc.Cookies$$anonfun$decodeSetCookieHeader$2]- Couldn't decode the Cookie header containing:
[play.api.http.MediaRange$parse$]- Unable to parse part of media range header 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
```

while the real request is this:

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9004
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 32
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:9004
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:9004/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=9575695e1e49712b0ec695b9e7384ac59c728302-token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9pYWlzLmlyIiwic3ViIjoiMDA2MjAwMDAxMiIsImJlZ2luVGltZSI6IjE0Mzk4MjcyODA0OTYiLCJyZW1lbWJlck1lIjoiZmFsc2UiLCJpYXQiOjE0Mzk4MjcyODB9.lCIAO1cRFmcHxchlbsUvGiHB79r006fimUCMCPwyGvQ
```

I use activator v1.3.5 and scala v2.11.6

Comment: Did you ever solve this?